# MMF in AC windings

Tags: electrical-engineering, motors

I have recently studied that the mmf produced by the stator in an electrical machine varies as a rectangular wave over the air gap periphery of the machine;
And to make the wave similar to a sinusoidal wave we use techniques such as distributing the winding,short pitching the coils or using a current sheet.

My question is,Why should I go through this process?Why not leave it as a rectangular wave,Since these processes reduce the mmf peak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could actually leave the MMF rectangular (in fact [brushless DC motors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brushless_DC_electric_motor) are synchronous motors with a rectangular MMF) but there is a drawback: the torque induced by a rectangular MMF under steady conditions is much less constant. There is a torque ripple in the form of harmonics (the sinusoidal harmonics that are in the rectangular MMF).

Comment: What is stable condition?

Comment: Torque ripples do you mean that the torque will vary like a sinusoidal wave or will it go in immediate high to  low and vice versa cycle?